# mongodb - Return a slice of sorted collection from specific element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My documents are

```
{sequence: 0, section: A}
{sequence: 1, section: B}
{sequence: 2, section: C}
{sequence: 3, section: F}
{sequence: 4, section: D}
{sequence: 5, section: E}
```

Now I want to sort them by section, and return 2 elements, starting at sequence X.

for example, my documents after sort are:

```
{sequence: 0, section: A}
{sequence: 1, section: B}
{sequence: 2, section: C}
{sequence: 4, section: D}
{sequence: 5, section: E}
{sequence: 3, section: F}
```

for sequence 5 => (sections E and F)
for sequence 1 => (sections B and C)

Can I do it with mongodb queries ?

Thank you.

Comment: post the sample output as well

Comment: Please don't re-post questions. You already posted the same question and the only "expected" result is that somebody copies content from the clear duplicate question you were already pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

instead of sorting you can do as follows
[$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) for greater than or equal
[$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) for greater than

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({'section':{$gte:'B'}}).limit(2)

db.getCollection('collectionName').find({'section':{$gte:'D'}}).limit(2)
```